# Shows error “Cannot POST” when I try to submit the HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

HTML code work fine. Here is my JS code:

```
 // Node.js JavaScript code

 const express = require ("express");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

   const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });


app.post('/', function (req, res) {

var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
 var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);

  var result = num1 + num2;

  res.send("the result is"+ result);

});


 app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("starting");
  });
```

I have seen many similar question but none of them worked. Packages are properly installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this error appears because you're trying to post a different route in your index.html

Please give it a try and let me know if it works. It would be helpful if you post the full error message.

Comment: thanks for answering. but its not working  full error is "Cannot POST /index.html"

Comment: I guess this error appears because you're trying to post a different route in your index.html. Could you show us your index.html

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

      <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>calcultor</h1>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="first number">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="second number">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">calculate</button>

  </form>

</body>

</html>

Comment: could you try change action to "/" instead of "index.html"?

Answer (score 0):

The js code seems fine, as you can see the

```
 app.post('/', function (req, res)
```

handles post requests in the '/' url, so just check your HTML file, if the form submits the data on this '/' url only.

```
<form action='/' method='post'>
...
...
<form/>
```

The action attribute will send the post data to the mentioned URL.